# Querying by Spotify ID in Echo Nest API

Tags: spotify, echonest

I've got songs from spotify play lists and need to get their information in EN.
Take “All I Want” by Tania Bowra for example.

```
EN ID(not given):    SOUJWUH13E89D89DED

Spotify ID:          2TpxZ7JUBn3uw46aR7qd6V

Spotify URI:         spotify:track:2TpxZ7JUBn3uw46aR7qd6V

Spotify external ID: AUCR10410001 (isrc)
```

If I query by the Spotify external ID or the Spotify ID in EN, like

```
$curl -X GET "http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/profile?api_key={my_api_key}&id=AUCR10410001&bucket=audio_summary" | python -m json.tool
```

or

```
$curl -X GET "http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/profile?api_key={my_api_key}&id=2TpxZ7JUBn3uw46aR7qd6V&bucket=audio_summary" | python -m json.tool
```

the EN API returns this message: `"id - Invalid parameter: id must be an Echo Nest id or foreign id"`.

Or if I query by the Spotify URI, like

```
$curl -X GET "http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/profile?api_key={my_api_key}&id=spotify:track:2TpxZ7JUBn3uw46aR7qd6V&bucket=audio_summary" | python -m json.tool
```

I get this response:

```
{
    "response": {
        "songs": [],
        "status": {
            "code": 0,
            "message": "Success",
            "version": "4.2"
        }
    }
}
```

which contains no information.

But as Spotify's [website](https://developer.spotify.com/spotify-echo-nest-api/#disqus_thread) says, it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with "song" modified to "track":

```
$curl -X GET "http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/track/profile?api_key={my_api_key}&format=json&id=spotify:track:2TpxZ7JUBn3uw46aR7qd6V&bucket=audio_summary"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace '**id**' with '**track_id**' and it will work.

Example:

```
$curl -X GET "http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/profile?api_key={my_api_key}&track_id=spotify:track:2TpxZ7JUBn3uw46aR7qd6V&bucket=audio_summary" | python -m json.tool
```